# How to invert relationship in MySQL Workbench 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, diagram

Hi i want to create a relationship ( 1.1 ) (0. N) between two tables in a ER diagram.

```
Tab 1.                           Tab 2
Id tab2
Foreign key Tab 2             Id tab 2
```

But i cant use the inverted relationship option someone can help me ?

I change the order but the foreign key is created in the wrong tables

Comment: Your need is unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to invert a relationship. You have to delete and recreate it in the reverse direction. Use the relationship tools from the vertical palette to quickly do this.